# What does this router-log file mean?

Tags: router, logging, ping

I was just checking the router's logs to see what kind of information is stored, and I find this file:

```
"May 14 21:13:36  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:89.170.246.114) detected."
"May 14 21:13:28  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:89.170.246.114) detected."
"May 14 21:12:41  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:77.1.237.165) detected."
"May 14 21:12:34  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:77.1.237.165) detected."
"May 14 21:12:32  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:90.50.156.104) detected."
"May 14 21:12:31  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:77.1.237.165) detected."
"May 14 21:12:31  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:190.164.165.139) detected."
"May 14 21:12:29  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:90.50.156.104) detected."
"May 14 21:12:28  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:190.164.165.139) detected."
"May 14 21:12:00  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:81.164.108.34) detected."
"May 14 21:11:54  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:81.164.108.34) detected."
"May 14 21:11:51  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:81.164.108.34) detected."
"May 14 21:10:20  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:176.58.245.155) detected."
"May 14 21:10:16  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:176.58.245.155) detected."
"May 14 21:10:14  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:176.58.245.155) detected."
"May 14 21:10:03  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:178.119.213.62) detected."
"May 14 21:09:57  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:178.119.213.62) detected."
"May 14 21:09:54  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:178.119.213.62) detected."
"May 14 21:03:21  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:88.167.57.184) detected."
"May 14 21:03:15  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:88.167.57.184) detected."
"May 14 21:03:12  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:88.167.57.184) detected."
"May 14 21:02:04  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:62.87.233.44) detected."
"May 14 21:01:55  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:62.87.233.44) detected."
"May 14 21:01:15  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:176.58.245.155) detected."
"May 14 21:01:11  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:176.58.245.155) detected."
"May 14 21:01:09  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:176.58.245.155) detected."
"May 14 21:00:04  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:84.193.34.126) detected."
"May 14 20:59:58  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:84.193.34.126) detected."
"May 14 20:58:53  ","Xmas port scan attack from WAN (ip:85.230.107.60) detected."
"May 14 20:58:47  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:178.119.213.62) detected."
"May 14 20:58:44  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:81.164.108.34) detected."
"May 14 20:58:41  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:178.119.213.62) detected."
"May 14 20:58:38  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:81.164.108.34) detected."
"May 14 20:58:38  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:178.119.213.62) detected."
"May 14 20:58:35  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:81.164.108.34) detected."
"May 14 20:56:53  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:138.38.187.151) detected."
"May 14 20:55:10  ","Xmas port scan attack from WAN (ip:85.230.107.60) detected."
"May 14 20:53:12  ","DHCP: Server sending ACK to 192.168.0.111. (Lease time = 86400)"
"May 14 20:53:12  ","DHCP: Server receive REQUEST from 70:54:d2:3b:b0:9f."
"May 14 20:52:55  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from N/A (ip:192.168.0.1) detected."
"May 14 20:52:07  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from N/A (ip:192.168.0.1) detected."
"May 14 20:52:05  ","DHCP: Client receive ACK from 195.130.132.103, IP=178.119.152.209, Lease time=7200."
"May 14 20:49:31  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:176.58.245.155) detected."
"May 14 20:49:27  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:176.58.245.155) detected."
"May 14 20:49:25  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:176.58.245.155) detected."
"May 14 20:47:00  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:188.155.203.92) detected."
"May 14 20:46:54  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:188.155.203.92) detected."
"May 14 20:46:51  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:188.155.203.92) detected."
"May 14 20:46:35  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:84.198.77.152) detected."
"May 14 20:46:30  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:84.198.77.152) detected."
"May 14 20:46:27  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:84.198.77.152) detected."
"May 14 20:43:55  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:72.69.2.75) detected."
"May 14 20:43:50  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:72.69.2.75) detected."
"May 14 20:43:47  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:72.69.2.75) detected."
"May 14 20:43:43  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:90.162.112.218) detected."
"May 14 20:43:37  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:90.162.112.218) detected."
"May 14 20:43:34  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:90.162.112.218) detected."
"May 14 20:41:34  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:109.72.37.191) detected."
"May 14 20:41:27  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:109.72.37.191) detected."
"May 14 20:41:18  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:84.193.34.126) detected."
"May 14 20:41:16  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:88.165.2.242) detected."
"May 14 20:41:10  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:88.165.2.242) detected."
"May 14 20:41:07  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:88.165.2.242) detected."
"May 14 20:40:36  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:95.90.39.85) detected."
"May 14 20:40:27  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:95.90.39.85) detected."
"May 14 20:40:14  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:81.164.108.34) detected."
"May 14 20:40:13  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:178.119.213.62) detected."
"May 14 20:40:10  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:178.119.213.62) detected."
"May 14 20:40:08  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:81.164.108.34) detected."
"May 14 20:40:05  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:81.164.108.34) detected."
"May 14 20:40:05  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:178.119.213.62) detected."
"May 14 20:38:50  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:78.94.76.158) detected."
"May 14 20:38:46  ","Xmas port scan attack from WAN (ip:85.230.178.204) detected."
"May 14 20:38:36  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:90.42.202.97) detected."
"May 14 20:38:30  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:90.42.202.97) detected."
"May 14 20:38:27  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:90.42.202.97) detected."
"May 14 20:38:14  ","DHCP: Server sending ACK to 192.168.0.110. (Lease time = 86400)"
"May 14 20:38:14  ","DHCP: Server receive REQUEST from 00:0c:f6:be:d5:aa."
"May 14 20:37:43  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:81.250.81.58) detected."
"May 14 20:37:37  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:81.250.81.58) detected."
"May 14 20:37:31  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:81.250.81.58) detected."
"May 14 20:37:23  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:176.58.245.155) detected."
"May 14 20:37:19  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:176.58.245.155) detected."
"May 14 20:37:17  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:176.58.245.155) detected."
"May 14 20:37:00  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:109.90.236.78) detected."
"May 14 20:36:54  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:109.90.236.78) detected."
"May 14 20:36:53  ","Xmas port scan attack from WAN (ip:85.230.178.204) detected."
"May 14 20:36:51  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:109.90.236.78) detected."
"May 14 20:34:23  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:84.198.77.152) detected."
"May 14 20:34:23  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:86.169.77.167) detected."
"May 14 20:34:21  ","Xmas port scan attack from WAN (ip:88.91.136.177) detected."
"May 14 20:34:17  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:84.198.77.152) detected."
"May 14 20:34:14  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:84.198.77.152) detected."
"May 14 20:33:56  ","Xmas port scan attack from WAN (ip:2.81.36.50) detected."
"May 14 20:32:20  ","PING-FLOODING flooding attack from WAN (ip:84.147.65.161) detected."
```

...

... and it goes on.

Is this some kind of DDOS-attack (I'd highly doubt it) or is it just normal to get this amount of ping requests?

I'll mention that our internet provider yesterday labeled us as "big spenders" and we're now forced to surf on narrowband for the rest of the month.
It might be a stupid question, but at least I'll learn something.

Thanks.

Comment: The logs state some miscreant has it in for you. Sit tight, and weather the storm...

Comment: Is this a business or residential connection?

Comment: Residential....

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it seems to be exactly what it says it is.  If you mail your ISP the logs, perhaps it'll get you reinstated on broadband, as it's clearly not traffic you desired.